# Compare two dictionary with more value in one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I just have one question if in one of my dictionary i have more value than the other can i still compare both dictionary or i have to change my code ? For example like this:

My code:

```
for key in result:
     if result[key]!=result2[key]:
            print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

output:

```
result={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
result2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}
```

Comment: In this scenario, you'll miss out on the `aba` and `meze` keys, but if it were the other way around with assigning `result` and `result2` your code would result in a `KeyError` because the abovementioned keys are not in the second dictionary

Comment: Then the value must be stored using other data structure like dict or list or tuple. e.g: {"jazi":[1,3],"juge":(2,4)}

Comment: This looks like XY problem. What exactly is your goal? You can use set operations to compare keys instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `get()` as the others have suggested is the simplest solution, but if you wanted you could be more specific than just saying "not equal":

```
result={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
result2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}

print("Only in result:", ", ".join(set(result).difference(result2)))
print("Only in result2:", ", ".join(set(result2).difference(result)))

for key in set(result).intersection(result2):
     if result[key]!=result2[key]:
            print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

Gives:

```
Only in result: 
Only in result2: aba, meze
juha not equal
jazi not equal
juge not equal
```

Or possibly a bit clearer:

```
keys, keys2 = set(result), set(result2)
print("Only in result:", ", ".join(keys - keys2))
print("Only in result2:", ", ".join(keys2 - keys))

for key in keys & keys2:
     if result[key]!=result2[key]:
            print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

which is exactly the same but pre-computes the sets so you can use inline operators `-` for `.difference()` and `&` for `.intersection()`.

Or if you do just want the 'not equal' message:

```
keys, keys2 = set(result), set(result2)

for key in (keys ^ keys2) | {
        key for key in keys & keys2 if result[key] != result2[key] }:
    print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
result={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
result2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}

for key, value in result.items():
    if value != result2.get(key, 0):  #You can add additional condition to check if key present in `result2`
        print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

**Output:**

```
jazi not equal
juge not equal
juha not equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but do not use `dict['key']` and use `dict.get('key')`. Below is the code which won't give you an error for any number of keys.

```
for key in result:
    if result.get(key, "")!= result2.get(key, ""):
        print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your both dictionaries can have different keys too. So you need to iterate on the combination of keys present in both dictionaries. For that you may use `set` to get uniques list of keys from both dictionaries as:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
>>> dict2 = {'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

>>> my_keys = set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()) # To get unique keys from both dicts

>>> my_keys
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
```

Now, in order to get item from dict, use `dict.get(key)` instead of `dict[key]`. `dict[key]` raises `KeyError` exception if the key is not found in the dictionary. Whereas `dict.get(get)` returns `None`.

Hence your code to iterate the dictionary should be like:

```
for key in my_keys:
    if dict1.get(key) != dict2.get(key):
        print("{} is having different value".format(key))

# which will print:
#     a is having different value
#     c is having different value
#     b is having different value
```

**Note:** Since `dict.get` returns `None` if the key is not found, above code won't return correct result if some key is not present in one dict, and same key is present in other dict with value as `None`. In that case, you should use `dict.get` with default value as `dict.get(key, default_value)` (where `default_value` should be value/string which will never be present as value in your dict)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have nested dicts, the `set()` approach could bring something (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for more info)

```
result={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
result2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}

set_1 = set((k, v) for k, v in result.items())
set_2 = set((k, v) for k, v in result2.items())

print(f"not equals: {sorted(list(set1 ^ set2))}")
# not equals: [('aba', 7), ('jazi', 1), ('jazi', 3), ('juge', 1), ('juge', 4), ('juha', 1), ('juha', 9), ('meze', 9)]
print(f"only in first: {sorted(list(set_1 - set_2))}")
# only in first: [('jazi', 1), ('juge', 1), ('juha', 9)]
print(f"only in second: {sorted(list(set_2 - set_1))}")
# only in second: [('aba', 7), ('jazi', 3), ('juge', 4), ('juha', 1), ('meze', 9)]
```

Comment: Putting the values into the sets could be a problem if the values aren't hashable.

Comment: But if they are... god, how much headhache you can save by using sets!

Comment: Oh indeed, that's why I posted a set based answer as well. It all depends on what exactly the OP wants.